# Having trouble with linking javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, constants

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menulinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

// Display Mobile Menu
const mobilemenu = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menulinks.classlist.toggle('active');
};

menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu ) ;
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh sans', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 80px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center ;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

     
     


.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 11px 50px;
}


#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%)
    background-size  100%; 
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
   -moz-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
           -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
        display: table;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 3rem;
       
    
       }

       .navbar__menu {
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           list-style: none;
           padding: 10px -100px;

       }

       .navbar__item {
           height: 80px;
       }

       .navbar__links {
           color: #fff;
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
           width: 125px;
           text-decoration: none;
           height: 100%;
           font-size: 1.5rem;
           transition: all 0.3s ease;
        
       }

       .navbar__btn {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           padding: 4 5rem;
           width: 100%

       }

       .Button {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-size: 1.5rem;
           padding: 10px 20px;
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
           border:none;
           outline: none;
           border-radius: 4px;
           background: #833ab4;
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); 
           background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); 
           color: #fff;
           transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .navbar__links:hover {
            color: #0d628a;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .Button:hover {
            color: #000000;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            .navbar__container {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          height: 80px;
          z-index: 1;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 1300px;
          padding: 0;    
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scroll Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar Section -->
   
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
       <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">Lolipop</a>
      tion
       <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
           <span class="bar"></span>
           <span class="bar"></span>
           <span class="bar"></span>
         
       </div>       
       
       <ul class="navbar__menu">
           <li class="navbar__item">
               <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__item">
                <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
             </li>
             <li class="navbar__item">
                 <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
             </li>
             <li class="navbar__Btn">
                 <a href="#sign-up" class="Button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
             </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <scripts src="Modify.js"></scripts>
     
     
    </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

I just cant know what is it that i did wrong... which is why i came here as a last resort help me pls.

AS you can already see..... i have done everything correct.... but i don't know if this this text editor bug(i'm using vs code) or its just me... help me solve these
and pls forgive me if i'm writing the wrong thing lol

well i just need the answer to this stuff pls..... THank you guys

Comment: Your function is `mobilemenu`, all lower case. in your addEventListener, you have `mobileMenu`, with an upper case M

Answer (score 1):

The tag to link a script is `<script>` not `<scripts>`

Answer (score 0):

Please use **script** instead of **scripts**.it won't work and I suggest you to use sublime text 3 or Notepad ++ with vs code like me. It can save you from many headaches. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors with code.

**HTML**

- `<scripts src=""></scripts>` is not valid HTML. You must `<script src=""></script>`
- Relocate script to bottom of HTML just before the closing `<\body>`. Remove from just before closing `</nav>`

**Javascript**

- To create a function you can:

  - Expression: `const mobileMenu = function() { // code goes here }`
  - Declaration: `function mobileMenu() { // code goes here }`
  - Arrow: `const mobileMenu = () => { // code goes here }`. While this is valid code you can not use it as a callback within the event listener as is. Running this function as is will attempt to look for classList on the window object which doesn't exist. You would need instead use `const mobileMenu = (e) => { e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active') }`
- The event listener is attached to the wrong element. Listen for click event on `.navbar__item` not `.navbar__menu`. You will also need to use `querySelectorAll('.navbar__item')` instead of `querySelector('.navbar__item')` in order to select all elements.
- Lastly, you'll need to cycle through each element using a `forEach()`.

**CSS**

- There isn't a closing bracket that closes out your media query.
- Presently there are no declared styles for `.active` and `#mobile__menu`

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#mobile-menu");
const menulinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar__item");

// Display Mobile Menu
function mobileMenu() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
}
menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu)
menulinks.forEach((link) => link.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kumbh sans", sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 11px 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%)
    background-size 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: table;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px -100px;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4 5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.Button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #833ab4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #0d628a;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.Button:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar Section -->

    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">
        <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">Lolipop</a>
        tion
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar__menu">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page"
              >Services</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__Btn">
            <a href="#sign-up" class="Button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="./Modify.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```